# How to initialize the SDK of the Parse server with master key [Angular 7]

Tags: angular, parse-server, angular7

In order to do a specific request on a Parse server, i need to use the master key.

I tried to initialize it but it seems like i don't do it the right way because i still have this error : *ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot use the Master Key, it has not been provided.*

Here's my code :

```
Parse.initialize('myAppId', '', 'myMasterKey');  // appID, js key & master key
(Parse as any).serverURL = 'https://myServerUrl';
```

Maybe the problem is due to the fact that the js key is empty in the params (my project only use a masterkey). Any help will be welcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did manage to find a solution.
i finally did not put the masterkey in the initialize :

```
Parse.initialize('myAppId', ''); // appID, js key
(Parse as any).serverURL = 'https://myServerUrl'; // use your server url
(Parse as any).masterKey = 'myMasterkey';
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I am guessing that this is in Angular on the client.  In which case, you do not want to use the master key.  If I were to load your page, I would be able to grab your master key and see the url of your parse server and I would be able to read any data using the rest api of your parse server.  I would be able to create or delete any data I wanted to.

The way to solve this problem is to use [cloud code](https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/) on your server.  So for example, if you wanted to allow 'user a' to send an email to 'user b', you wouldn't be able to do it on the client, because without the master key, there is no way to get 'user b's email on to the client of user a.

So, you create a cloud function `sendEmail` that accepts two parameters: the id of the user to email and the message to send.  The untested code would look something like this:

```
const sendEmail = async function sendEmail(request) {
   const { user: sender } = request;
   const { id, message } = request.params;
   const recipient = await Parse.Query(Parse.User).get(id, { useMasterKey: true });
   console.log(recipient.get('email')); // now we have the user's email!
   ..... // code to actually send email here...
}

Parse.Cloud.define('sendEmail', sendEmail);
```

And then you can call it from your front end like:

```
Parse.Cloud.run('sendEmail', { id: 'objectId', message: 'hi' });
```

This pattern allows you to do privileged things like getting a user's email without revealing your master key to anyone who loads your page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
This was not the purpose of this post, i simply wanted to use the masterkey and that was the issue.
I will use the cloud code on my Parse server for this project but not for the moment.